# How to set Z axis in RVIZ?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I'm using a drone and to be display in RVIZ, I need to have a Z axis to see the height of the drone to ground.

However, my RVIZ got only the X and Y axis. Only views in 2D. My robot's frame does not go up or down, only can navigate around the 2D plane. Anyway I can set?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215706/how-to-set-z-axis-in-rviz?/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-08-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like RVIZ view is set to TopDownOrtho. You want to change it to Orbit.

First make sure that the panel "Views" is visible. Next to "File" is menu called "Panels". Click "Panels" and click "Views" so that it has a check mark next to it.

Next on the view panel there is a drop down box labelled "Type:". Change it to "Orbit (rviz)".

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-13**:
Thanks for the help!